# 2 loops to insert data in my database(mysql) using reactjs(frontend) and nodejs/expressjs(backend)

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am stuck trying to insert 2 values in an object that has **2 arrays in it.** I tried looping through the 1st object, then the 2nd, but whenever I insert the data, it only inserts the value (the second loop)at index 0 instead of inserting the value at index 0,1 and so on. For example, it would only insert the value **Air Canada** instead of inserting **Air canada and Air Canada Rouge**

Here is the code and picture below to view the JSON file in order to get a better picture of my problem (the yellow highlights in my picture are the key things to look for)

**Code (React)**

```
addClosedCRs = _ => {

    this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues && Object.keys(this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues).map((issue, i) => (
      this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues && this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].fields && this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].fields.customfield_11400 && Object.keys(this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].fields.customfield_11400).map((field, customfield_11400_index) => (
        fetch(`http://ca-fpscfb2:2000/ClosedCRs/add?supNumber=${this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].key}&Airline=${this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].fields.customfield_11400[customfield_11400_index].value}&Product=${this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].fields.customfield_11600.value}&Title=${this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].fields.summary}&Status=${this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].fields.status.name}&DateCRRequestReceived=${this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].fields.created.slice(0, 10)}&EcrNumber=${this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].fields.customfield_10800}&supNumberLink=<div><a target="_blank" href="http://ksr-ca-qmaltjira.ca.kronos.com:8061/browse/${this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].key}">${this.state.jiraCLOSEDCRsAccepted.issues[i].key}</a></div>`)

      ))
    ))


  }

componentDidMount(){
 this.addClosedCRs();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why `customfield_11600` in the fetch string ?

Comment: Oh its a value I am getting from the first loop to insert in my database

Comment: Any ideas why it wouldn't insert the 2nd value?